# Group fields into ranges - Excel

Tags: excel

In my Excel file I have a spreadsheet with sites and visits and an other spreadsheet where I want to group my sites into ranges according to their visits eg class "0-10 visits" where "a", "b", "c" sites belong etc. 
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could use the FREQUENCY function.   It is an array formula.   FREQUENCY(data_array, bins_array)

where data_array is the data values you want to group and bins is an array of "bins" (really it would be the top value for each group.   So if you wanted 0-10, 11-20,21-30, etc......than you would set up a column (or row) with 10,20,30 etc., select a group of cells equal to the number of bins you created with *all* of those cells created enter the formula, and hit Ctrl + Shift + Enter. The picture hopefully makes it a bit clearer.   The brackets { and } are not typed - they will appear after pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter and are there only to indicate that this is an array formula.

[image: Frquency array]

Comment: The problem is that I want to paste the names of each site for each range, not the number of them. In your example I want maybe a drop down list under each result field that would include the names of the sites.

Comment: I'm confused as to your expected output.   If you have a drop down for the websites and you simply want the corresponding number of hits to show as a range of 10, you could do so by creating drop down with data validation and in the adjacent cell use a combination of vlookup, ceiling and floor to get that result.  I'm not in front of a computer right now, so the code below was not able to be tested.   If you were to have the drop down on the same page in cell d1 for example, in the preceding example I gave,  something like.      =floor (vlookup (d1, a2:a8, 2, 0),10 & " - " & ceiling (vlookup (

Comment: I was able to test now.   I had to modify it slightly.  This should do the trick assuming I understand your expected outcome now.   If the number of hits is a multiple of 10, you would get 30-30 or 20-20, etc.  If that works you can leave it.  If now a simple if statement could resolve that however you wish to resolve it.  
    =FLOOR(VLOOKUP(D1,A2:B8,2,0),10)&" - "&CEILING(VLOOKUP(D1,A2:B8,2,0),10)